# Ionic form with pagination

Tags: forms, ionic3, ngfor

I have a massive set of array data which I am trying to display in a form one index at a time.

I am trying to display each array item in an individual form, one form at a time. So instead of ngFor looping through my array and printing on the same page, I need only one array index at a time on the page. And then when I click a button, the next array index can be loaded.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hope this plunker may be help you to achieve pagination http://plnkr.co/edit/vPXf2U?p=preview

Comment: @SurajBahadur: Thank you. I will investigate that in detail and let you know

Comment: @SurajBahadur: How do I place my own content? I don't see where to place the content i:e ITEM 1 - ITEM 10.